# Threejs: There is no texture bound to the unit 1

Tags: three.js

I am working on a glb viewer with threejs r116. In order to display metalness correctly, I add an environment map to the mesh.

Without the environment map, the model displays black, as expected. With the envMap it shows correctly but the console throws: RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 1.

```
 model.traverse(n => {
     if(n.isMesh){

         if(n.material.metalness === 1){
             n.material.envMap = cubeTexture
         }

         n.castShadow = true
         n.receiveShadow = true
     }
})
```

I tried setting a 1x1px white texture but couldn't figure out how to make that work.

This is how I create the cube texture:

```
let loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader()
let cubeTexture = loader.load([
    './images/envMap/posx.jpg', './images/envMap/negx.jpg',
    './images/envMap/posy.jpg', './images/envMap/negy.jpg',
    './images/envMap/posz.jpg', './images/envMap/negz.jpg'
])
```

Comment: Can you please show how you load/create `cubeTexture`?

Comment: Sure thing, I edited the post with the cube texture code.

Comment: What happens if you do this `scene.environment = cubeTexture;` instead of assigning it to `envMap`? Do you see the same warning?

Comment: Yes, if I assign it to scene.environment I do get the same warning.

Comment: Any chances to share your code as a GitHub repository?

Comment: Sure, you can find the threejs code starting on line 264. https://github.com/maxibenner/threejsviewer

Comment: THX for sharing your code. However, I was hoping you share your entire project in a way so I can locally execute and debug it. If that's not possible, can you maybe host the application somewhere?

Comment: Ah I see. I just started using github and have to learn best practices. I updated the repo with all the files for the basic version of the viewer: https://github.com/maxibenner/threejsviewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely ignore this warning. This happens because you are trying to use an environment map among other texture before it is actually loaded.

`three.js` allocates a texture unit as soon as a texture is applied to a material. However, the actual texture binding and upload can only be done after the texture has completely loaded. Firefox and Safari don't even log a warning in this case (at least on macOS).

If you want avoid the warning, start loading your `glTF` asset in the `onLoad()` callback of `CubeTextureLoader.load()`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This was the most convenient answer I could hope for!